# SQL Unpivot multiple columns Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I am using SQL server 2008 and I am trying to unpivot the data. Here is the SQL code that I am using,

```
CREATE TABLE #pvt1 (VendorID int, Sa int, Emp1 int,Sa1 int,Emp2 int)
GO
INSERT INTO #pvt1  VALUES (1,2,4,3,9);

GO

--Unpivot the table.
SELECT distinct VendorID,Orders,Orders1
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Sa,Emp2,Sa1
   FROM #pvt1 ) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Emp IN 
      (Emp1,Emp2)
)AS unpvt
UNPIVOT
   (Orders1 FOR Emp1 IN 
      (Sa,Sa1)
)AS unpvt1;
GO
```

And Here is the result of the above code.

```
VendorID    Orders  Orders1
1            4      2
1            4      3
1            9      2
1            9      3
```

But I want my Output to be the way indicated below

```
VendorID    Orders  Orders1
1           4       2
1           9       3
```

The relationship from the above code is 2 is related to 4, and 3 is related to 9.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: FWIW .. the following link helped me ... http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/04/unpivot-multiple-columns.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

An easier way to unpivot the data would be to use a CROSS APPLY to unpivot the columns in pairs:

```
select vendorid, orders, orders1
from pvt1
cross apply
(
  select emp1, sa union all
  select emp2, sa1
) c (orders, orders1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f20b/3).  Or you can use CROSS APPLY with the VALUES clause if you don't want to use the UNION ALL:

```
select vendorid, orders, orders1
from pvt1
cross apply
(
  values 
    (emp1, sa),
    (emp2, sa1)
) c (orders, orders1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f20b/4)

Comment: wow... this is super useful yet I've never bothered with it.   I need to get up to speed on CROSS APPLY.

Comment: This is a glorious alternative to unpivot code. I love CROSS APPLY!

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Taryn is indeed super useful, and I'd like to expand one aspect of it.

If you have a very un-normalized table like this, with multiple sets of columns for e.g. 4 quarters or 12 months:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+
| cYear | foo1 | foo2 | foo3 | foo4 | bar1 | bar2 | bar3  | bar4 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+
|  2020 |   42 |  888 |    0 |   33 | one  | two  | three | four |
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+
```

Then the CROSS APPLY method is easy to write and understand, when you got the hang of it. For the numbered column, use constant values.

```sql
SELECT 
    cYear,
    cQuarter,
    foo,
    bar
FROM temp

CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    (1, foo1, bar1),
    (2, foo2, bar2),
    (3, foo3, bar3),
    (4, foo4, bar4)

) c (cQuarter, foo, bar)
```

Result:

```
+-------+----------+-----+-------+
| cYear | cQuarter | foo |  bar  |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+
|  2020 |        1 |  42 | one   |
|  2020 |        2 | 888 | two   |
|  2020 |        3 |   0 | three |
|  2020 |        4 |  33 | four  |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a8890/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

I needed composit key AND skip extras row in case when data is missing (NULLs). For ex. when x2 and y2 are possible replacement vendor and price

```
WITH pvt AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
   ( 1, 6, 11, 111, 12, 13, 122, 133),
   ( 2, 6, 21, 211, 22, 23, 222, 233),
   ( 3, 6, 31, 311, 32, 33, 322, 333),
   ( 5, 4, 41, 411, 42, NULL, 422, NULL),
   ( 6, 4, 51, 511, 52, NULL, 522, NULL))
   s( id, s, a, b, x1, x2, y1, y2)
)
-- SELECT * FROM pvt

SELECT CONCAT('xy_',s,'_', id, postfix) as comp_id, a, b, x, y 
FROM pvt
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    (NULL, x1, y1),   
    ('_ext', x2, y2)

) c (postfix, x, y)
WHERE x IS NOT NULL
```

produces

```
comp_id                          a           b           x           y
-------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
xy_6_1                           11          111         12          122
xy_6_1_ext                       11          111         13          133
xy_6_2                           21          211         22          222
xy_6_2_ext                       21          211         23          233
xy_6_3                           31          311         32          322
xy_6_3_ext                       31          311         33          333
xy_4_5                           41          411         42          422
xy_4_6                           51          511         52          522

(8 rows affected)
```

from:

```
id          s           a           b           x1          x2          y1          y2
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           6           11          111         12          13          122         133
2           6           21          211         22          23          222         233
3           6           31          311         32          33          322         333
5           4           41          411         42          NULL        422         NULL
6           4           51          511         52          NULL        522         NULL
```

(5 rows affected)

Comment: Please introduce your answer with an independent statement "Or may be" is proposing an alternative solution but as opposed to what? Are you referring to another answer? The original question?