# SQL SERVER - CHANGE COLUMN NAME TO VALUE

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Date 1     | Date 2     | Date 3
1  | 2014-08-01 | 2014-08-02 | 2014-08-03
```

And I need to output it like this:

```
ID | Date Field Name | Date Value
1  | Date 1          | 2014-08-01
1  | Date 2          | 2014-08-02
1  | Date 3          | 2014-08-03
```

Have tried dynamic unpivoting with unions but seems messy. Is there a best practice way of doing this?

Comment: cross apply should help you

Comment: How will it help me?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617243/sql-unpivot-multiple-columns-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `UNPIVOT` is the best practice here. I don't find it messy so much as confusing, maybe because I don't reach for it that often. This will give the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT ID, [Date Field Name], [Date Value]
FROM myTable
UNPIVOT ([Date Value] FOR [Date Field Name] IN ([date 1], [date 2], [date 3])) AS x
```

Comment: Thanks, I had some problems with this query I think because one of the fields was a computed column but I managed to get round it was using my original dynamic sql query.