# SQL Pivot Questions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data like below:

```
Year January Feb March April
2017  20     15  7     25
```

Is it possible to format the data to

```
Year Month  Value

 - 2017 January 20 
 - 2017 Feb     15 
 - 2017 March   7 
 - 2017 April   25
```

Thanks a lot for your help. I have been trying to achive this for hours but I am not able to.

Comment: So [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617243/sql-unpivot-multiple-columns-data) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `unpivot`, but I prefer using `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t outer apply
     (values (t.year, 'January', t.January),
             (t.year, 'Feb', t.Feb),
             (t.year, 'March', t.March),
             (t.year, 'April', t.April)
     ) v(year, month, value);
```

`apply` implements something called a "lateral join".  This is a lot like a correlated subquery that can return multiple columns.  Lateral joins are very powerful -- unpivoting is just the beginning of what they do.  But unpivoting is one way to start learning about them.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, is there any reason why you like apply over unpivot

Comment: @Agga . . . I thought I explained that in the question.  `apply` is a general purpose, powerful operator.  `unpivot` exists just for one specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for this.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Year INT, January INT, Feb INT, March INT, April INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2017,20,15,7,25)

SELECT [Year], [Month], [Value] FROM @T 
    UNPIVOT( [Value] FOR [Month] IN( [January], [Feb], [March], [April] ) ) AS UNPVT
```

Result

```
Year        Month       Value
----------- ----------- -----------
2017        January     20
2017        Feb         15
2017        March       7
2017        April       25
```

Comment: You are awesome!! it worked