# Unpivot Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, unpivot

I need some help to solve this Problem. I have a SQL Server table that has a similar structure like this.

I Need to unpivot Article, Amount and Price. (Notice i don't have a Price 1)

[image]

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Im using SQL Server

Comment: I was guessing i Need to do that but i don't know how to write the unpivot code..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Unpivot multiple columns Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617243/sql-unpivot-multiple-columns-data)

Answer (score 1):

Use `cross apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.id, t.article1, t.amount1, NULL),
             (t.id, t.article2, t.amount2, t.price2),
             (t.id, t.article3, t.amount3, t.price3),
             (t.id, t.article4, t.amount4, t.price4)
     ) v(id, article, amount, price)
where v.article is not null;
```